# folder access at login screen

Tags: macos, file, authentication, directory, save

(MAC)
hi... i m using a policy banner application which writes something on a database as the user inputs it and lets him log in. It works perfectly when i have logged in. But when i launch it in real time. it does not work...issue is that i m saving my .sqlite database in documents folder which i dont think are accessible at login screen time. THERE MUST be one folder available where i could place my sqlite database file 
OR DO I HAVE to use login hook... issue with login hook is that my 1st app (Paycreditcard) has stopped once the user logs in so the information cannot be extracted from it...

I NEED A FOLDER OR PLACE WHERE I COULD SAVE AND EDIT MY .SQLITE FILE AT LOG IN TIME>>>>

stuck :(

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its /Applications/utilities that is accessible at logintime... FOR FUTURE USERS